# Set pythonpath having two different versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix, qgis

Im working on a CentOS 6.5 which has Python 2.6.6 and I also have installed Python 2.7.5

The problem is that I want to import qgis and works with Python 2.7.5.

In python 2.6.6 if I write

```
from qgis.core import *
```

There is no problem, but when I tries with Python 2.7 by typing scl enable python27 bash and impor the moudle it returns

```
from qgis.core import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

Any help? I try adding into PYTHONPATH the path where qgis is installed but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please use Python virtual environments if you need to support multiple Pythons and multiple application on the same computer:

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing/#creating-virtual-environments

EXample to create a virtual environment and install qgic there:

```
  virtualenv -p python2.7 venv  # Create Python installation in venv folder
  source venv/bin/activate  # Activate this environment
  pip install qgis   # Replace this with installation instructions from qgis package
```